# TextView items depending on Spinner value [Android]

Tags: java, android

I wanna create `TextView` list depending on chosen value from Spinner in Android. Here's the essential code with a problem:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        TextView pMember = new TextView(this);
        pMember.setText("asd");
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
The constructor TextView(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){}) is undefined
```

I've tried `parentView.this` instead `this` reference, but it also didn't work out.
I have programming `ADT` almost for a week, so I haven't got much experience. Have you got any ideas how to resolve my issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass an AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener as param in your constructor because you do that inside your listener.

Try:

```
TextView pMember = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
```

Instead of:

```
TextView pMember = new TextView(this);
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `textview` outside the `onItemSelectedMethod` as following:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
TextView pMember = new TextView(this);
```

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    pMember.setText("asd");
}
});
```